# Mercurial: Unable to push to remote repository after pull-merge-commit

Tags: mercurial

I can't figure out why i'm still unable to push to a remote repository:

```
> hg pull
pulling from ......
searching for changes
no changes found

> hg merge
abort: branch 'default' has one head - please merge with an explicit rev
(run 'hg heads' to see all heads)

> hg heads
changeset:   12942:...
tag:         tip
parent:      12940:...
parent:      12941:...
summary:     merge

> hg branches
default                    12942:...

> hg commit
nothing changed
```

and finally

```
> hg push
pushing to ...
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote heads on branch 'default'!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)
```

why would that be?

Comment: what does 'hg branches' output?

Comment: did you update before merging?

Comment: Did you mean 12942 in the output of hg branches, or is it really 12842?

Comment: 12942, i made hg branch on another repo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why, but this solved the issue:

> hg push -r tip

where -r is

> -r --rev REV [+]            a changeset intended to be included in the destination

Comment: Though now every time i push i had to specify -r tip... There must be a way to fix it.

Comment: Try hg heads and then behead one of the heads

Comment: @SeunOsewa Can you be specific how to "behead one of the heads"? Thanks.